# Shortest path in an undirected graph in LogSpace

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

Given an undirected graph $G$ (can be cyclic) with the promise that all its faces have $3$ sides, is it possible to find the minimum distance between a source and any other vertices in LogSpace or in LogDCFL, at least under the constraint that between any two vertices there are polynomially many paths?

Comment: @StefanKohl: Please limit the flood of minor edits to a handful per day. See http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/599 .

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: o.k..

Comment: What do you mean by "all its faces have 3 sides"? Faces are not a concept that makes sense for arbitrary (non-planar) graphs. And when you say "between any two vertices there are polynomially many paths", you mean simple paths, right? But in an undirected graph that's still a very strong restriction.